# Can I indicate mapping file using relative paths in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping

I am developping a standalone application with hibernate, using the following stucture for my project : 
[image]

This is how I told hibernate(yes, I'm chatting with Hibernate) where to find the hibernate.cfg.xml file :

```
File hibernateConfigurationFile = new File("..\\resources\\hibernate.cfg.xml");
...
Configuration().configure(hibernateConfigurationFile).buildSessionFactory();
```

This is how I told hibernate where to find the Event.hbm.xml file :

```
<mapping resource="../resources/test/Event.hbm.xml"/>
```

I also tried :

```
<mapping resource="test/Event.hbm.xml"/>
```

But when I compile it, I have the following error :

> Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: test/Event.hbm.xml not found

I understand it is because I indicated the wrong mapping file path in my hibernate.cfg.xml file. So I moved my Event.hbm.xml file, and the structure of my project is now : [image]

And all works fine.

My problem is that I would like to keep my Event.hbm.xml in the resource\test directory. How can I indicate that in my hibernate.cfg.xml file? I tried relative paths, but it doesn't work. I read hibernate documentation, but found nothing. Any suggest?

Comment: Are you building it using maven?

Comment: no, i'm using ms-dos command line. I don't want to use maven, although i know it'd be better.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but its more like a packaging issue. Try this: resources/test/Event.hbm.xml

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the resources folder added in classpath?? You will need to have it, since you not using maven here and these are just different folders. Maven structure is of no significance if not using maven.

Comment: I added the resource folder to the classpath, but it can't still find the mapping file.

Comment: Once added resource folder on classpath, Try with: test/Event.hbm.xml

Comment: Great to hear you got it working.

Comment: Mark as answer so can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [programmatic way of building hibernate configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic) and can say

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration()
    .addFile("yourpath/Event.hbm.xml")
```

instead of declaring mapping resource in `hibernate.cfg.xml`

see [this method](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addFile%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: Ok! Programmatic configuration you suggested works! Any idea how to do that with xml file?

Comment: What i understood from your question is that you want to externalize the mapping files (keep it in some directory you want). Hence i thought of explaining how it could be done using programmatic configuration

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem

I used this

```
<mapping file=".\hibernate\groupResult.hbm.xml" />
```

Means there is an attribute file in mapping

> .\hibernate\groupResult.hbm.xml

will be in your project folder in that hibernate folder in that groupResult.hbm.xml

Hope this will help you!

Cheers!